Batch script to retrieve computer specification is returning weirdly formatted values
So here two example codes and what they return.
Code:
@echo off
hostname >> "C:\test.txt"
wmic cpu get name >> "C:\test.txt"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('ipconfig ^| findstr "IPv4" ^| findstr [0-9]') do echo %%i >> "C:\test.txt"

Output:

Station1


N a m e
I n t e l ( R )   C o r e ( T M )   i 5 - 3 5 7 0   C P U   @   3 . 4 0 G H z
192.168.1.109

Notice how there is a space added between each letter when the value for the CPU name is returned? This also applies if I try other wmic commands such as wmic memphysical get MaxCapacity.

Alternatively, if I rearrange the code like so:
@echo off
wmic cpu get name >> "C:\test.txt"
hostname >> "C:\test.txt"
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%i in ('ipconfig ^| findstr "IPv4" ^| findstr [0-9]') do echo %%i >> "C:\test.txt"

The output is correctly spaces but now is missing the non-wmic commands and comes up with with random chinese like so:
Name                                     
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3570 CPU @ 3.40GHz  
敔档瑳瑡潩㍮਍ㄠ㈹ㄮ㠶ㄮㄮ㤰ഠ

What am I missing here that is causing the outputs to appear like this?
I would be fine with the code from example one but it would be additional work with output that has a bunch of spaces between the letters.

Why is a Windows batch script tagged bash?

The output from your wmic command is in UTF16-LE, (2 bytes per character), which has defined the output file as such. Your hostname and ipconfig output is in ASCII, (1 byte per character), so an additional character has to be inserted after each. You could try using wmic cpu get name | more instead.

That makes sense why the wmic commands are adding an additional character after each.
Although I added the | more as you suggested and while the format is now much better, there are now 5 new line characters after the wmic command

That's because wmic doesn't use a standard CrLf line ending, (and is technically a new question).

for /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%G IN ('wmic cpu get name /value') do for /f "delims=" %%I in ("%%~H") do >test.txt echo %%~I

As Compo in the comments said, the reason why example 1 code had a bunch of spaces after each character was because wmic commands are UTF16-LE which are 2 bytes per character while hostname is ASCII which is only 1 byte.
While I was unable to figure out how to convert the wmic without adding additional characters, I figured out if I created a file with the wmic commands to one file named "output.tmp" and the rest to another named "test.txt" and then appended them together like:
TYPE "C:\output.tmp" >> "C:\test.txt"
I got the desired output without any additional or strange characters.

Did you not see the code in my comment below your question?

The WMI command-line utility outputs data always in Unicode using UTF-16 little endian encoding with byte order mark. The other used commands output text using a single byte per character encoding according to the code page as defined by the country/region configured for the used account. There can be executed chcp in a command prompt window to get displayed the used code page. The resulting text file is therefore a mixture of different character encodings which no text viewing or editing application can handle correct.
One solution is processing the output of deprecated wmic before writing the data of interest into a file.
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
(
    if defined COMPUTERNAME (echo %COMPUTERNAME%) else if exist %SystemRoot%\System32\HOSTNAME.EXE %SystemRoot%\System32\HOSTNAME.EXE
    if exist %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe for /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe CPU GET NAME /VALUE 2^>nul') do for /F "delims=" %%K in ("%%J") do echo(%%K
    for /F "tokens=2 delims=:" %%I in ('%SystemRoot%\System32\ipconfig.exe ^| %SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R /C:"\<IPv4 .*: [0-9][0-9.]"') do for /F "tokens=*" %%J in ("%%I") do echo(%%J
) 1>"%USERPROFILE%\TestData.txt"
endlocal

This batch file opens first the file TestData.txt in the user's profile directory which is for sure not write-protected in comparison to root directory of the system drive. An existing TestData.txt is overwritten because of using the redirection operator > instead of >>.
Everything output by the commands inside the command block defined with ( and matching ) to handle STDOUT is redirected into this opened file which is kept open as long as not all commands inside the command block have been executed.
The computer name is a predefined environment variable which is preferred used by the code as the output of the string value with command echo is faster than the execution of an executable.
It is possible on computers with Windows 10/11 22H2 or newer that wmic.exe is not installed anymore as it became an optional Windows component since 22H2 of Windows 10 and Windows 11. The batch file checks for that reason first the existence of the executable before running it by calling in background:
%ComSpec% /C %SystemRoot%\System32\wbem\wmic.exe CPU GET NAME /VALUE 2>nul

The Unicode output of perhaps not anymore installed wmic.exe program is captured by cmd.exe processing the batch file and special processed to work around the quirks which the Windows Command Processor has on processing UTF-16 encoded output. See also the Microsoft documentation for the Win32_Processor class.
The output of ipconfig is filtered with a regular expression by findstr and then processed with two for /F loops to get only the IPv4 address(es) written into the file without leading spaces.
All executables are referenced with their fully qualified file names for making the batch file execution as fast as possible, fail-safe and secure. The Windows Command Processor does not need to search for any executable using the environment variables PATHEXT and PATH on execution of this batch file.
